# Search form works on local machine, but not on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, refinerycms

Am Dienstag, 30. Juli 2013 12:23:46 UTC+2 schrieb Steven Stadler:

Hey guys! I did create a search form for an extension of the standard refniery app. This extension stands for publications which can be found with three search terms like "author", "date" and "title".
    It works on my local machine. After I deploy it to heroku I just get this error message ... "We're sorry, but something went wrong."
    I hope someone can help me ... I use Rails 3.2.13 and Ruby 1.9.2 and 2.0.0

Here is a part of the full log:

```
    2013-07-30T10:14:32.782472+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:143:in `pass'
    2013-07-30T10:14:32.782472+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:155:in `invalidate'
    2013-07-30T10:14:32.782472+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
    2013-07-30T10:14:32.782472+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
    2013-07-30T10:14:32.782472+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
    2013-07-30T10:14:32.782114+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
    2013-07-30T10:14:32.782624+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
    2013-07-30T10:14:32.782624+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
    2013-07-30T10:14:32.782472+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
    2013-07-30T10:14:32.782624+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
    2013-07-30T10:14:32.782472+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:71:in `call!'
    2013-07-30T10:14:32.782624+00:00 app[web.1]:
    2013-07-30T10:14:32.782624+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
    2013-07-30T10:14:32.782624+00:00 app[web.1]:
    2013-07-30T10:14:32.782472+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
    2013-07-30T10:14:32.782624+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
    2013-07-30T10:14:32.782472+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
    2013-07-30T10:14:32.784993+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/extensions/publications/app/views/refinery/publications/publications/index.html.erb within layouts/application (721.8ms)
    2013-07-30T10:14:32.784993+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 738ms
    2013-07-30T10:14:32.784993+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Refinery::Publications::PublicationsController#search as HTML
    2013-07-30T10:14:32.784993+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"88vYJKWcs7Xjb/OGHVYg13AW5SibRJGk8OvQrbeliqA=", "search_author"=>"ang", "search_title"=>"", "search_year"=>"", "commit"=>"Search", "locale"=>:en}
```

My routes (from the extension):

```
    Refinery::Core::Engine.routes.append do

      # Frontend routes
      namespace :publications do
        resources :publications, :path => '', :only => [:index, :show]
        match '/get_pubs' => 'publications#search'
      end


      # Admin routes
      namespace :publications, :path => '' do
        namespace :admin, :path => 'refinery' do
          resources :publications, :except => :show do
            collection do
              post :update_positions
            end
          end
        end
      end

    end
```

My search form:

```
    <% content_for :body do %>
      <ul id="publications">

    <%= form_tag "/publications/get_pubs", method: :post do %>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
      <b>Author:</b>
    </td>
    <td>
      <b>Title:</b>
      </td>
      <td>
      <b>Year:</b>
      </td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
      <%= text_field_tag :search_author, '' %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= text_field_tag :search_title, '' %>
      </td>
      <td>
      <%= text_field_tag :search_year, '' %>
      </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
    <% end %>

    .....
```

My Model:

```
    module Refinery
      module Publications
        class Publication < Refinery::Core::BaseModel
          self.table_name = 'refinery_publications'

          attr_accessible :title, :authors, :year, :publisher, :position

          acts_as_indexed :fields => [:title, :authors, :publisher]

          validates :title, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true

           def self.search(query1,query2,query3)
             # where(:title, query) -> This would return an exact match of the query
             where("authors like ?", "%#{query1}%").where("title like ?", "%#{query2}%" ).where("year like ?", "%#{query3}%" )
           end
        end
      end
    end
```

My Controller:

```
    module Refinery
      module Publications
        class PublicationsController < ::ApplicationController
          before_filter :find_all_publications
          before_filter :find_page

          def index
            # you can use meta fields from your model instead (e.g. browser_title)
            # by swapping @page for @publication in the line below:
            present(@page)
          end

          def show
            @publication = Publication.find(params[:id])

            # you can use meta fields from your model instead (e.g. browser_title)
            # by swapping @page for @publication in the line below:
            present(@page)
          end

          def search
            @publications = Publication.search(params[:search_author],params[:search_title],params[:search_year]).order("year").reverse_order
            #@publications = @publications.first
            render action: 'index'
          end


        protected

          def find_all_publications
            @publications = Publication.order("year").reverse_order
          end

          def find_page
            @page = ::Refinery::Page.where(:link_url => "/publications").first
          end

        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: Add a full log because noone here can guess what exception was thrown just from looking on a backtrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things happening here.  First is that you are likely developing against SQLite which behaves differently than PostgreSQL.  I'd recommend setting up a local Postgres install to develop against if you are going to be deploying to Heroku as it will allow you to catch these problems sooner and save you a lot of headaches.  This [tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql) is a helpful place to start.

As for the specific problem you're having, Postgres LIKE is string compare only but as the logs show you are trying to do a LIKE on the year column which is an integer.  I can't test this to be sure, but replacing the search clause in your model with something like this should solve the problem:

```
where("authors like ?", "%#{query1}%").where("title like ?", "%#{query2}%" ).where("year::text like ?", "%#{query3}%")
```